# How to override Interface of Other custom module?

Tags: magento2, module, overrides, interface

I have tried with preference to override interface as below in **di.xml** file

```
<preference for="Custom\Module\Api\Data\AccountInterface" type="Override\Module\Api\Data\AccountInterface" />

<preference for="Custom\Module\Model\Account" type="Override\Module\Model\Account" />
```

And My Interface file is like as below

> Override\Module\Api\Data\AccountInterface.php

```
<?php

namespace Override\Module\Api\Data;

interface AccountInterface extends \Custom\Module\Api\Data\AccountInterface {

    const AFFILIATE_ID = 'custom_id';

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getCustomId();

    /**
     * @param string $custom_id
     *
     * @return \Custom\Module\Api\Data\AccountInterface
     */
    public function setCustomId($custom_id);
}
```

Override Model File with new method Logic as below

> Override\Module\Model\Account.php

```
<?php

namespace Override\Module\Model;

use Custom\Module\Api\Data\AccountInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Model\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource;

class Account extends \Custom\Module\Model\Account {
   /**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getCustomId() {
    return $this->_getData('custom_id');
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function setCustomId($customId) {
    $this->setData('custom_id', $customId);
    return $this;
}
}
```

But it's not save the value of custom_id using setter and getter methods...

If use same  setter and getter method and Model logic in Custom_Module directly then it's working fine.

Any solution of add custom method in Interface ?

> note :- **extension_attribute** method is not available inside 
>   **Custom\Module\Api\Data\AccountInterface** so how we can use it ?

Comment: You cannot override interface classes. Use extension attribute featured instead. If not you need to create your own interface

Comment: extension_attribute method is not available inside Custom\Module\Api\Data\AccountInterface so how we can use it ?

Comment: You need to create your new custom interface. There is no option.

Comment: @rakeshprajapati, did you found solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

Magento 2 Preference does not allow us to override the interfaces. Preferences are used to specify the implementation classes for the interfaces and overriding implementation classes. **It does not allow to override interface with an interface**

Then, how can we override the interfaces to send our extra informations over the interface? That's where the beautiful concept comes in - **Extensions Attributes**.

From the official doc:

> Extension attributes are new in Magento 2. They are used to extend
>   functionality and often use more complex data types than custom
>   attributes. These attributes do not appear on the GUI.

In your case, if you check the `\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterface` interface, you can find these 2 methods at the bottom, which helps you to send your shipping information through this methods.

```
 /**
 * Retrieve existing extension attributes object or create a new one.
 *
 * @return \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupExtensionInterface|null
 */
public function getExtensionAttributes();

/**
 * Set an extension attributes object.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupExtensionInterface $extensionAttributes
 * @return $this
 */
public function setExtensionAttributes(\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupExtensionInterface $extensionAttributes);
```

For more information on how to add extension attributes,
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html

Comment: extension_attribute method is not available inside Custom\Module\Api\Data\AccountInterface so how we can use it ?

Comment: it may have been a long time, but I want to know how you solve it if there is no extension attribute in Custom\Module\Api\Data\AccountInterface. Or just add getExtensionAttributes() and setExtensionAttributes() in custom module ? it's possible to do, I think all modules in magento have extension_attribute method